# "group by" feature from windows explorer in

Tags: linux, image-viewer

[image: group by feature in windows explorer]

Windows Explorer has this feature to organize files in a folder into groups, each having it's own header, very convenient. Is there a Linux file or image explorer with a similar feature?

Comment: What 'linux` disro ?

Comment: Make it Debian.